# Ngx-graph doesn't show properly nodes and edges

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-graph

I'm trying to create a graph with the ngx-graph library(I'm new with it).I'm trying to create nodes and edges in a dynamic way. I get the info from a service and I push these data into two separate array(Nodes and Edges). Thw problem is the data are pushed properly but my graphic create nodes and edges in the same position.(x=0 and y=0). I tried also to force the position but don't change.

```
 <ngx-graph *ngIf="nodes.length > 0 && links.length > 0 && !loading"
    layout="dagre"
    [view]="[800,500]"
    [links]="links" 
    [nodes]="nodes">
  </ngx-graph>
```

And in my .ts component I add the nodes and edge:

```
createGraph() {

   this.nodes = [];
   this.links = [];

   if (this.items) {

   this.nodes.push({
      id: this.items.id,
      label: this.items.description
   });


  if (this.items.motivations) {
    let i = 0;
    for (let motivation of this.items.motivations) {
      ++i;
       this.nodes.push({
         id: motivation .id,
         label: motivation .description
       });

       this.links.push({
         id: motivation .id,
         source: this.nodes[0].id,
         target: motivation .id 
       });
    }

  }
  this.loading = false;
}
```

}

And at the end I always this error in console

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dimension' of undefined
    at swimlane-ngx-graph.js:2016
    at Array.map ()
    at QueryList.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.QueryList.map (core.js:5412)
    at GraphComponent.push../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm5/swimlane-ngx-graph.js.GraphComponent.applyNodeDimensions (swimlane-ngx-graph.js:1988)
    at GraphComponent.push../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm5/swimlane-ngx-graph.js.GraphComponent.draw (swimlane-ngx-graph.js:1796)
    at swimlane-ngx-graph.js:1768
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4053)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
```

Comment: Can your provide a minmal [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) which shows your error?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs from [ngx-graph](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/) how to [trigger an update](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/#demos/interactive-demo#triggering-update).

> The graph component updates itself on every input change. The inputs
>   are immutable, so in order to trigger the update, you would need to
>   pass a new object instance.

Example, this will **not trigger an update**, because we are modifying the nodes array in place, and not creating a new instance:

```
this.nodes.push(newNode);
```

We need to **create a new instance of the array in order to trigger change detection** in the component:

```
this.nodes.push(newNode);
this.nodes = [...this.nodes];
```

To manually trigger the updade, the graph accepts an update$ input as an observable:

Comment: I have the same issue, but your solution is not working for me. Still looking for an answer.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For me, the issue was a real 'Gotcha'. in ngx-graph, node id's are treated as strings. As I was setting them as a number, the mismatch caused this problem.